# how to get back on ubuntu to free space?

Tags: disk-usage

I tried to download something on ubuntu and it said I have no space on my device. so I decided to log out of ubuntu and get to my regular computer to check my space. It said I had no space so I tried to go back to ubuntu but I can't because I have no space. I downloaded a lot while on ubuntu and I can't access my files that I downloaded on ubuntu.

Comment: I suppose you should probably delete some of that stuff you downloaded. Without more detail, not much we can tell you. If you cannot login to Ubuntu, then use your LiveUSB, mount your disk, and delete some files.

Comment: Maybe the bleachbit software might help you free some space.

Comment: Also, what is your 'regular computer' as opposed to 'ubuntu'?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

It will delete all cached files by the apt application.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: The user can't log back into Ubuntu, so they'll never be able to do this. Thanks for trying though.